# Вывести на экран множество точек из двумерного массива

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Пишу игру "Жизнь", нужно вывести на экран двумерный массив точек, не соединенных линиями.

Есть ли функции для вывода на экран двумерного массива (например если число 1, то точка черная, а если 0 - то белая)?

Есть функция `glDrawArrays`, но она рассчитана на одномерный массив, его неудобно обрабатывать, приходится добавлять сдвиг.

Comment: Может быть это текстура? `MIPMAP_NEAREST` ;-)

Comment: Не, не текстура. Координаты точек просчитываются.

Comment: Так вы и текстуру можете каждый кадр менять, попиксельно ;-)